# Why Apple plant is dying?

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees

As you can see in photo the leaves seems like they starting to wither/burn. I suspected the stalled growth for a month but now this. How can I save/grow apple plant into a tree?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the leaves are lighter green which can be not enough sun and the tip burns can be not enough water or sun. You will also have to investigate what type of apple tree it is. Most apple tree do well outside in real cold weather and rarely any are to be in a very sunny area. It can also be because they are not getting enough nutrients to keep growing. Think of how we eat and need nutrients to grow when we are smaller.

https://www.canr.msu.edu/uploads/files/Applenutrition-EricHanson.pdf